# -[__NSCFNumber value1]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-iphone-3

```
-(FileGame *)objectAtXandY:(int) posX secondPos:(int)posY
{

    if (posX < 0 || posX >= kBoxWidth || posY < 0 || posY >= kBoxHeight)
    return OutBorderStart;

    return (FileGame*)[[content objectAtIndex:posY]objectAtIndex:posX];
}

-(void) checkWith:(BOOL)orien
{
int iMax = (orien == isLandscape) ? size1.width : size1.height;
int jMax = (orien == isPortrait) ? size1.height : size1.width;
for (int i=0; i<iMax; i++) 
{
    int count = 0;
    int balValue = -1;
    for (int j=0; j<jMax; j++)
    {
      FileGame* tile =[self objectAtXandY:(orien == isLandscape) ?i :j secondPos:(orien == isPortrait) ?j :i];

      [readyToRemove addObject:tile];   
 }
}
FileGame* square = [readyToRemove objectAtIndex:2];
    square.value1 = 0;
  if(square.value1==balVal)
  {
    //some thing to do  
  }
else{
//some thing to do
}
}
```

Here readyToRemove is NSMutableArray,balVal is int,FileGame is CCNode.While i run this i'm getting 
-[__NSCFNumber value1]: unrecognized selector sent to instance error help me.

Comment: Your array `readyToRemove` contains `NSNumber`and not `FileGame` object. Check how you fill that array.

Comment: Yes i'm having the FileGame Object only. 2 is a index value of the array

Comment: edit your post with the code you use to fill the array, i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: What is a OutBorderStart ?  probably an NSNumber by the looks of it.

Comment: it is a FileGame Object

Comment: Please use `NSLog(@"Assigning %@ to 'square'", [readyToRemove objectAtIndex:2]);` just before you make the assignment and add the result to your question.

Comment: show how you populate content in method -(FileGame *)objectAtXandY:(int) posX secondPos:(int)posY

Answer (score 1):

The object at index 2 of that array is not a `FileGame` object.  It's a `NSNumber`.  Either you've populated the array in a way you didn't intend or, more likely, the object you expected to find there has been released and the address re-used for a different object.

Turn on zombies in your scheme and you will probably get a better error message.

Also, try logging the value of `square` when you assign it and verify the data type.

Answer (score 0):

Becareful objective-c isn't really type safe until runtime. I would check your code to make sure you're not putting NSNumber's into that array. Put a break point after you pull it out of the array you'll see.